# Django CSRF failure, using React forms

Tags: django, reactjs, csrf

I'm having a problem with CSRF with Django and React.

I have read through the already high number of questions around this, as well as the django docs naturally. I have tried every possible combination of different things that should address the issue but am still struggling with it.

Firstly I tried to create a register page, but when I POST to register/ I get CSRF cookie not set, 403.

I have gone so far as disabling the CSRF middleware [bad I know, just trying to get somewhere] and I am getting 405s, method not allowed [attempting to post]. I just thought maybe this is something someone has run into before or sounds familiar and could give some guidance?

I have tried:
- adding the decorator @csrf_exempt, 
- adding the CSRF to the header of a request, 
- attaching the whole cookie, 
- attaching a hidden form field with the token.

I am using this seed project: https://github.com/Seedstars/django-react-redux-base if anyone wants to have a look, I've done a bit in React, but not a lot on the Django side, so it isn't far off what's there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not disable the csrf check in django.
Instead in your form/template simply do 
`{% csrf_token %}` **not `{{ csrf_token }}`**
It will print a hidden form element with value assigned to your csrf token already.

If you are using ajax, you can simply set your ajax headers globally as:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            // this time double brackets
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{csrf_token}}"); 
        }
    });
```

if you are using fetch then:

```
fetch('some/url/here', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // or pass it in your own way
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
```

These are pretty much all the ones i can think of.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done but to no avail. When I look at the request headers of the request, I do notice that although I have 'X-CSRFToken' in the code, it shows as 'x-csrftoken', but I don't think this is an issue either?

Comment: What version of django are you using? can you post a copy of your headers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Justin! I'll edit the post to include the code, thanks!
Version of Django is 1.8.15

Comment: Did you fix this error? I am stuck on the same issue. It would be great if you can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: My sincere apologies I only saw this now, did you resolve the issue? I believe I had messed around with middleware, there wasn't a problem with any of this stuff. Let me know if you're still struggling and I can look back over exactly what I did